# Encode and pad netbios name using python

Tags: python, netbios

I'm trying to create a simple script that will convert a string (max 15 chars) to a netbios name (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194203) :

```
name = sys.argv[1].upper()
converted = ''.join([chr((ord(c)>>4) + ord('A'))+chr((ord(c)&0xF) + ord('A')) for c in name])
print converted
```

Trying to convert the name : "testing"
will return : "4645454646444645454a454f4548" which is correct.
Now depending the length of the name submitted (max 15 chars) we need to pad 4341 until the converted string is 64 long.
Example :

```
./script.py testing:
4645454646444645454a454f4548
```

But should actually be :
    4645454646444645454a454f4548434143414341434143414341434143414341

Anyways to do this easily ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... + ((16 - len(name)) * '4341')
```